# Is there a simple backup program in existance that will perform a SHA256 hash check to verify data?

Tags: backup, sha256, robocopy, certutil

I'm trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.  Typically I use robocopy in a bat file to backup my data but it doesn't perform data verification.  Has anyone written a simple program to backup data with a hash check or do I need to write something?  I'm trying to avoid all of the corporate bloatware.